# Why "What helps " not "what does help"

Tags: questions

So I know the first one is correct but a friend of mine asked me for a grammatical reason.

So my question is why don't we use does with help while making a question

Like "what does help people" instead of "what helps people"

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to ELL!

"Does" can be used for emphasis, but it isn't necessary here.

If someone tells you, "You don't help people," you might contradict them and say, "I DO help people".

Or if you are asked, "What helps people?" you might say, "I don't know. What DOES help people?"

But most of the time we simply say we help people, or we ask what helps people, and it is the same with any pronoun and with any verb.

Comment: Would add that "help" is not a special case, nor are questions a special case.  Normally you would say "I cook" instead of "I do cook" and "Who cooks?" or "Who's cooking?" instead of "Who does cook?"  The word "does" is, of course, required in the negative - "She doesn't cook."

Answer (score 1):

In a question, you use the auxiliary ***does*** *when the wh- word is NOT the subject* of the verb or does not modify the subject:

> ***What*** *does* he want? [*what* is the direct object of *want*]
> ***What** song* *does* he like singing? [*what* modifies the direct object of *like singing*]

If ***what*** is the subject, there cannot be [*subject-auxiliary inversion*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv207.shtml), because being an interrogative word, it needs to head the interrogation:

> ***What*** helps people? (subject-auxiliary inversion would be **Does what help people?*)

The same goes for *what* modifying the subject:

> ***What** philosophy* helps people? (subject-auxiliary inversion would be **Does what philosophy help people?*)

You can find this rule on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion), too:

> I*nversion does not occur when the interrogative word is the subject or is contained in the subject*. In this case the subject remains before the verb (it can be said that ***wh-fronting takes precedence over subject–auxiliary inversion***).